# Show gif while clicking in a key

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to make a gif appear while I m clicking in Ctrl key but when I stop I want to show an image.

My code make the gif appear when I click Ctrl but if I stop the gif keeps.

CODE:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

if(event.keyCode == 17) {

document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"stick.gif\">";

shoot -= 1;

document.getElementById("shoot").innerHTML = shoot;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `keyup` handler?

Comment: I only have keydown handler.

Comment: Well, how do you intend to react to the `Ctrl` key being released without a `keyup` handler?

Comment: I made an  `if(event.keyCode == 17)` for react when the Ctrl key is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.I have made a key-up event that replaces the GIF when the key is not pressed.You can make this react specifically to the Ctrl key as well.I have added the two ID tags for elements, since you had not attached any HTML elements.

As the comment above mentioned, *you need a `Keyup` function to handle the event when the key is not pressed.*

```
<script>document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Event");
if(event.keyCode == 17) {
console.log("Key Pressed");
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"stick.gif\">";

shoot -= 1;

document.getElementById("shoot").innerHTML = shoot;
  }

});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "This key is up"

});

</script>
<p id="key">Hello</p>
<p id="shoot">Shot</p>
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot.